# How to make windows drive active?

Tags: windows, boot

I was facing some troubles with my laptop, so i tried to install the original windows that comes installed with it but **by mistake i change the active drive of the windows** to the drive that contains the installation of the original window.

The problem now my laptop **active drive is not the C drive** and i cant install any windows until i make it active, so how to make it active again ?

**Note:**

- when i switch on the laptop it ask me about boot media, so i need to change the drive using a utility without using the windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you boot from your windows recovery / install DVD then you should be able to follow the instructions [here](http://malwaretips.com/blogs/fix-computer-wont-start/) to set your active partition.

If this works for you, please let me know and I'll add the details to the answer.

Comment: Thank you, I created a repair recovery for my flash disk and followed the instructions.